# Testar classes com dependências (C# + Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testes-de-unidade

Tenho uma classe "Venda" (resumo da classe logo abaixo) e nela eu tenho uma propriedade "Orcamento". Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer um teste unitário nessa classe? Me deparei com 2 problemas:

- Os frameworks de mocks exigem que deixamos os métodos que precisamos "mockar" como virtual, o que eu acho um pouco arriscado abrir essa brecha de poder dar um override num método onde eu não vejo sentido de permitir isso, a não ser pela própria exigência do mock.
- Outro caminho seria criar uma interface para esta classe "Orcamento" para mockar a interface ao invés da classe em si, mas pelo que eu vi até agora, o Entity Framerwork não consegue resolver quando eu tenho uma propriedade como interface.

Qual o melhor solução ou a melhor prática para isso?

```
public class Venda
{
    public Venda(Orcamento orcamento)
    {
        this.VendaItens = new List<VendaItem>();

        if (orcamento.Valido() && orcamento.Pendente())
            this.CarregaItensAPartirDoOrcamento();
    }

    public Orcamento Orcamento { get; private set; }

    public IList<VendaItem> VendaItens { get; private set; }

    public VendaItem AdicionaProduto(Produto produto, int quantidade)
    {
        var item = new VendaItem(produto, produto.ValorUnitario, quantidade);

        this.VendaItens.Add(item);

        return item;
    }

    private void CarregaItensAPartirDoOrcamento()
    {
        foreach (var orcamentoItem in this.Orcamento.OrcamentoItems)
        {
            var item = new VendaItem(orcamentoItem.Produto, orcamentoItem.ValorUnitario, orcamentoItem.Quantidade);
            this.VendaItens.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência com isto e não vou responder mas você tem toda razão. Este *frameworks* ou mesmo metodologias exigem que se faça coisa terríveis com o código para solucionar coisas que eles se preocupam. Pra mim, para o que eu entendo e gosto, nenhuma destas soluções são aceitáveis. Complicar código para torná-lo testável nos padrões estabelecidos é uma péssima ideia. Na verdade eu já disse algumas vezes que dá para testar sem fazer estas coisas. Só que dá mais trabalho no teste. Mas acho melhor do que projetar pensando no teste. A testabilidade deve ser consequência, não requisito

Comment: @bigown, estaria você referindo-se, indiretamente, ao Design Patterns?

Comment: Eventualmente, mas não principalmente. Outras técnicas são mais danosas. SOLID por exemplo. Tudo nele pode ser bom se você precisa para o código atender as necessidades reais. Mas frequentemente vejo as pessoas aplicando porque mandaram, porque ajudam em algumas coisas secundárias, como para facilitar o teste. Testar é bom, mas colocar penduricalhos só para dar a impressão de custo baixo do teste, eu sou contra.

Comment: Excelente pergunta.

Comment: A maneira de como testar depende do que você quer testar. Testar uma classe não tem nenhum valor - o que testamos são **comportamentos**. Se você puder descrever as classes envolvidas e o objetivo do teste (qual comportamento você quer testar) fica fácil responder com um técnica de testes adequada. Já te adianto que dificilmente a solução implicará no uso mocks. Mocks, principalmente estes que vem em frameworks são altamente complexos e muito pouco úteis.

Comment: Por aquilo que vejo você não necessita de *Mocks* mas sim de *Fakes*. Assim sendo, criar manual um *Orcamento* e um par de *Produtos* é suficiente para fazer os testes.

Comment: @ramaral mesmo se a minha classe Orçamento for muito complexa e dependendo de outras classes como os produtos por exemplo e esta também for complexa? Pois hoje faço tudo manualmente como você diz, mas estou com problemas quando preciso modificar essas classes dependentes e preciso atualizar esses fakes, mesmo se a modificação não é relevante para a minha classe Venda e achei que mocks seriam mais apropriados.

Comment: Quando você necessita apenas de dados use *Fakes*. Quando a classe sob teste depende de resultados de métodos de outras classes(dependências) use *Mocks*.  Note que para criar um *Mock* você só necessita da *Interface* ou seja é possível criar *Mocks* sem ter a classe implementada. Se as suas classes tem muitas dependências(em profundidade) considere usar um IoC Container.

Comment: Unit testing é algo trabalhoso, deverá sempre ser equacionada a relação custo/beneficio de o fazer. Caso escolha fazê-lo aconselho que comece por escrever primeiro o teste e depois o código(TDD).

Comment: Essa classe `Venda` é um *Model*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Sim, é um model, estou tentando seguir a proposta do Domain-Driven Design

Comment: Péssima ideia. Acho que até já sei de onde você tirou a iniciativa. O autor dela veio discutir comigo esses dias. Recomendo você começar pelo mais simples, entender bem o MVC pra depois diversificar sua aplicação. Não coloque complexidade no sistema onde não precisa. Um *Model* MVC não é um POCO clássico.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o autor do livro Domain-Driven Design, Eric Evans? Estou procurando simplificar o máximo minhas regras de negócio e deixá-las independente de qualquer outra coisa (BD, Views), para fins de organização e manutenção e achei que casava com a proposta de desenvolver pensando no domínio do problema. E pelo que sei, posso utilizar muito bem o MVC também para isso, ficando a View e o Controller em uma camada mais externa e o Model no seu núcleo (Onion Architeture), podendo me focar ainda nos meus domínios.

Comment: Escrevi um texto falando sobre isso, que ainda não foi publicado. Defendo que o ganho de implementar o DDD em MVC é zero. Toda essa lógica comportamental que você colocou na classe é feita de outra forma no MVC, e o suposto ganho em organização e manutenção não existe, até porque o MVC precisa de um padrão organizacional pra funcionar corretamente, e o modelo de abstração faz você se concentrar no que é importante, que são as regras de negócio, e não em pormenores de manutenção. Disse antes e falo de novo: é melhor abandonar essa ideia de DDD em MVC.

Comment: Interessante! Por favor, mande o link de onde sairá seu artigo pra poder ler por favor @CiganoMorrisonMendez! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Comment: @RicardoKenjiHarasaki Saiu já: http://masterdesigners.com.br/quando-boa-pratica-vira-ma-pratica/

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez o link quebrou, tem como atualizar?

Comment: @Math Acho que o texto se perdeu completamente. [Tenho um outro texto semelhante aqui](http://codingcraft.com.br/2016/10/14/entity-framework-e-o-fim-da-era-dos-repositorios/).

Answer (score 7):

Vou passar uma maneira minha de testar. Não sei se é a melhor, mas pode ser um ponto de partida pra gente produzir algo mais conciso e coerente.

## O método de testes e *Mocks* do Cigano

Demorei bastante tempo pra encontrar algo que fosse bom o suficiente para um *Mock* e nunca encontrei. Os textos que encontro a respeito normalmente falam de tudo e não explicam nada, então resolvi fazer alguns *Mocks* caseiros que funcionam bem pro meu caso.

Vou passar uma série de passos pra produzir um modelo de testes rapidamente.

## Método 1: Não usando uma base pré-existente

Este método acho mais interessante do ponto de vista do teste porque não conta com uma base já pronta e seus vícios.

### Passo 1: Extrair a Interface de `DbContext` e usar `IDbSet` ao invés de `DbSet`

Extrair a interface do contexto é simples:

- Na classe do seu contexto, clique com o botão direito no nome dela, selecione **Refactor** > **Extract Interface**;
- O Visual Studio irá sugerir um nome. Clique em **Ok** para gerar a interface e modificar a classe de contexto para usar sua interface.

Vai ficar alguma coisa assim:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class MeuProjetoContext : DbContext, MeuProjeto.Models.IMeuProjetoContext
    { 
        ...
    }
}
```

Substitua agora todas as ocorrências de `DbSet` por `IDbSet`. Isto faz com que o sistema e o projeto de testes usem o mesmo contexto, mas com implementações de `DbSet` diferentes.

Ou seja, o meu ficou mais ou menos assim:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    public class MeuProjetoContext : DbContext, MeuProjeto.Models.IMeuProjetoContext
    { 
        ...
        public IDbSet<Colaborador> Colaboradores { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

### Passo 2: Crie um Projeto de Testes com os diretórios `Controllers` e `Models`

Essa parte não tem muito segredo:

[image: Criar Projeto de Teste]

### Passo 3: Crie um Contexto de Mentira em `Models` (no projeto de testes)

Estou supondo que aqui você já adicionou a referência do projeto principal no projeto de testes (botão direito em *Reference* > *Add Reference...*).

Instale também o Entity Framework no projeto de testes. Apenas adicionar a referência a `System.Entity.Data` não adianta.

O meu ficou assim:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Testes.Models
{
    public class MeuProjetoFakeContext : DbContext, MeuProjeto.Models.IMeuProjetoContext
    { 
        ...
        public IDbSet<Colaborador> Colaboradores { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

A vantagem é que toda e qualquer atualização na interface que você fizer fará você atualizar a interface do contexto de mentira com apenas um clique.

### Passo 4: Implemente um `FakeDbSet` genérico

O meu ficou assim:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Testes.Models
{
    public class FakeDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T>
    where T : class
    {
        HashSet<T> _dados;
        IQueryable _query;

        public FakeDbSet()
        {
            // Aqui não precisa ser HashSet. Pode ser uma Lista.
            _dados = new HashSet<T>();
            _query = _dados.AsQueryable();
        }

        public virtual T Find(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }
        public void Add(T item)
        {
            _dados.Add(item);
        }

        public void Remove(T item)
        {
            _dados.Remove(item);
        }

        public void Attach(T item)
        {
            _dados.Add(item);
        }
        public void Detach(T item)
        {
            _dados.Remove(item);
        }
        Type IQueryable.ElementType
        {
            get { return _query.ElementType; }
        }
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression IQueryable.Expression
        {
            get { return _query.Expression; }
        }

        IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
        {
            get { return _query.Provider; }
        }
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _dados.GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return _dados.GetEnumerator();
        }

        T IDbSet<T>.Add(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }

        T IDbSet<T>.Attach(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }

        public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, T
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }

        public T Create()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }

        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T> Local
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar."); }
        }

        T IDbSet<T>.Remove(T entity)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Derive a classe e este método para usar.");
        }
    }
}
```

### Passo 5: Crie classes estáticas em `Models` para inicializar seus `DbSets` de mentira

Vou dar um exemplo de como ficou uma configuração minha:

```cs
namespace MeuPrjeto.Testes.Models
{
    public static class ColaboradoresConfiguration
    {
        public static IDbSet<Colaborador> MontarMockColaboradores()
        {
            return new FakeDbSet<Colaborador>
            {
                new Colaborador { ColaboradorId = Guid.NewGuid(), DataCriacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), DataNascimento = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), UltimaModificacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate() },
                new Colaborador { ColaboradorId = Guid.NewGuid(), DataCriacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), DataNascimento = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), UltimaModificacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate() },
                new Colaborador { ColaboradorId = Guid.NewGuid(), DataCriacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), DataNascimento = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), UltimaModificacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate() },
                new Colaborador { ColaboradorId = Guid.NewGuid(), DataCriacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), DataNascimento = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), UltimaModificacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate() },
                new Colaborador { ColaboradorId = Guid.NewGuid(), DataCriacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), DataNascimento = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate(), UltimaModificacao = DateTimeHelper.RandomDate() }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

No construtor do *Mock* de mentira, ficaria assim:

```cs
    private MeuProjetoFakeContext()
    {
        Colaboradores = ColaboradoresConfiguration.MontarMockColaboradores();
    }
```

### Passo 6: Substituir os contextos do projeto original por interfaces

Aqui tem várias maneiras de fazer. O que eu fiz foi colocar o contexto num *Controller* base da seguinte forma:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers
{
    public abstract class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    {
        protected IMeuProjetoContext Context;

        protected Controller(IMeuProjetoContext _context = null)
        {
            // Aqui é o contexto de verdade mesmo que vai ser instanciado
            Context = _context ?? new MeuProjetoContext();
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

### Passo 6: Montar os *Controllers* de teste

Idealmente, os *Controllers* de teste chamam os *Controllers* reais, mas passando para o *Controller* este *Mock* que montamos. Um caso de teste ficaria assim:

```cs
namespace MeuProjeto.Testes.Controllers
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ColaboradoresControllerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestIndexView()
        {
            var fakeContext = new MeuProjetoFakeContext();

            var controller = new ColaboradoresController(fakeContext);
            var result = controller.Index("", null);
            // Testes sempre usam Assert.
            Assert.AreEqual("", result.ViewName);
        }
    }
}
```

Este teste é bem bobinho. Só pra mostrar o que dá pra fazer, e não deixar a resposta enorme.

## Método 2: Usando uma base pré-existente

Este é bem mais fácil de fazer, mas não tem características de teste unitário. Consiste em passar para o contexto uma *connection string* apontando para outra base, idêntica à base padrão do sistema, e usá-la para realizar os testes, modificar registros, etc.

## Conclusão

Na dúvida, acabo usando os dois métodos, mas com preferência para o primeiro no início do desenvolvimento. Para isso monto dois projetos de teste por sistema, e se me interessa realizar os mesmos testes usando bases diferentes, derivo um terceiro projeto contendo apenas as classes de teste.

Comment: Muito legal o seu método para poder testar minha camada de serviços sem precisar de frameworks de mocks!