# Utilizando Moq com MVC DotNet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, testes-de-unidade, moq

Estou usando MVC4 com Moq e gostaria de saber como faço para mockar o meu *Model* também e se isso é possível.

Obrigado.

Comment: É possível. Dentro da tag [tag:moq] há informações sobre tutoriais e exemplos que você pode usar para montar seus testes unitários. Clique em "Saiba mais..." para ter acesso ao Wiki.

Comment: Cigano não estou achando um exemplo mockando um banco de dados, você sabe aonde eu posso encontrar algo do tipo ? Porque no caso de testar a Model, eu precisaria mockar o banco de dados(componente de acesso ao banco de dados)...

Comment: [Veja isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79993/testar-classes-com-depend%C3%AAncias-c-entity-framework/80011#80011) antes de usar o Moq.

Comment: Legal, mas eu não estou usando o Entity, estou usando uma componente que só chamo na model e ele faz o acesso ao meu banco de dados. Mesmo assim eu conseguiria fazer ?

Comment: **Na Model**, é isso mesmo? Por que?