# Injeção de dependência MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência, moq

Galera estou usando injeção de dependência para utilizar o *Mock*. Gostaria de saber se preciso criar uma interface para minha *Model* e outra para minha *Controller*?

Obrigado

Comment: Qual a tecnologia que você está usando?

Comment: Estou usando MVC e C#

Comment: E para a injeção de dependência? O que está sendo usado?

Comment: Estou usando Interface para injeção de dependencia nas minhas camadas de Model e Controller

Comment: Não sei se estaria correto apenas responder que sim. [Nesta resposta, produzo interfaces apenas do contexto e dos `DbSet`s, sem necessariamente extrair as interfaces de *Models* e *Controllers*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79993/testar-classes-com-depend%C3%AAncias-c-entity-framework/80011#80011). Evito isso porque acho prolixo e desnecessário. Se você detalhar melhor o que quer usar quanto a tecnologias e *frameworks*, acho que posso chegar numa resposta melhor.

Comment: Estou usando MVC 4 padrão Microsoft sem divisão de camadas no projeto. Esse projeto tem que utilizar testes unitários e percebi que ficou ruim a forma que foi estruturado o sistema. Estou utilizando injeção de dependencia nas camadas de Model e Controller para poder fazer os testes unitários. Nos testes unitários estou usando moq. A minha duvida seria se eu teria que criar uma Interface para Model e uma para Controller para poder desacoplar as classes !!! Eu se teria uma outra maneira de fazer esse procedimento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não vejo como necessária a criação de uma interface para ambos. [Neste exemplo, o *Mocking* é realizado em cima de uma camada de serviços](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63369/ASP-NET-MVC-Injecting-Mocking-an-IRepository) e injetado usando [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). [Neste outro, do próprio site do ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/contact-manager/iteration-5-create-unit-tests-cs), mesma coisa.

O código da sua aplicação, ou seja, o que deve ser testado, não passará pelo processo de *Mocking* justamente porque é a parte que interessa ser testada. Não faz sentido fazer *Mocking* de um *Controller* porque é ele que receberá as entradas e executará as ações, devolvendo um resultado que não sabemos qual é. A função de um objeto de *Mock* é queimar etapas quanto à devolução de resultados de um método. Especificamos o que um *Mock* devolve quando configuramos seu comportamento da seguinte forma:

```
mock.Setup(obj => obj.VerificarSeStringEhVazia("oi")).Returns(true);
mock.Setup(obj => obj.VerificarSeStringEhVazia("")).Returns(false);
```

Mesmo assim, se você deseja fazer o *Mock* de *Controllers*, sim, você precisa extrair a interface deles.

Mesma coisa para *Models*. Entretanto, já adianto que o ganho para o seu teste de fazer isso é muito próximo de zero.

Comment: Cigano obrigado pela ajuda, agora está entendido, só gostaria de fazer uma ultima pergunta: Estou fazendo os testes na Model e existe o metodo1 que chama o medoto2 dentro dele e esse metodo2 chama o banco de dados. Como poderia fazer para mockar o metodo1?

Comment: Esses métodos pertencem ao *Model* e chamam o banco de dados? É isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim isso mesmo...

Comment: Isto não faz o menor sentido. Um *Model* não invoca a camada de dados. Ele é a representação de um registro da camada de dados. Tem algo **muito** errado no seu código. Mas, enfim, para *Mockar* o `metodo1`, é só usar como mostrei ali em cima: `modelo.Setup(m => m.Metodo1).Returns(true);`.

Comment: Desculpa Cigano é o método2 que preciso mockar.... Isso é possível ?

Comment: É possível, mas não vai ter muita utilidade fazer isso, até porque você disse que `metodo1` chama `metodo2`, e o resultado de `metodo1` você já está *mockando*.