# Como testar um controler asp.net mvc usando Moq e Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, testes, moq

Meu controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public class DominioController : Controller
    {

        private IDominioDB _db;

        public DominioController(IDominioDB db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        // GET: Dominio
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

            var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var d = await _db.Dominios.Where(x => x.idUsu == userID).ToListAsync();

            ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.Name;

            return View(d);
        }
    }
```

Meu método de teste:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task VERIFICA_CONTROLE_DOMINIO()
        {

            var data = new List<DBDominio>()
            {
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario1" },
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario2" },new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario2" },
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario3" },new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario3" }
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<DBDominio>>();


            mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<DBDominio>>()
                .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<DBDominio>(data.GetEnumerator()));

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<DBDominio>(data.Provider));


            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            var repo = new Mock<Interfaces.IDominioDB>();
            repo.Setup(c => c.Dominios).Returns(mockSet.Object);


            var context = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            var mockIdentity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
            context.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity).Returns(mockIdentity.Object);
            mockIdentity.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("usuario1");



            // Arrange
            DominioController controller = new DominioController(repo.Object)
            {
                ControllerContext = context.Object
            };

            // Act
            ViewResult result = (ViewResult)await controller.Index();

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewBag.Username , "usuario1");

        }
```

Quero saber como eu poderia verificar se o `var d = await _db.Dominios.Where(x => x.idUsu == userID).ToListAsync();` que está dentro do controler retorna a quantidade de registros certos, isso é possível dessa forma?

Eu sei que poderia criar uma camada de Serviços entre o controller e o EF, o que não gosto dessa solução é que daqui a algum tempo existem 200 métodos diferentes dentro de um serviço e comece a me dar problemas de manutenção.

Comment: [Veja se isso aqui ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/79993/testar-classes-com-depend%C3%AAncias-c-entity-framework/80011#80011). Se não ajudar, escrevo mais uma resposta.

Comment: Gostei da sua solução, mas com ela, como vc saberia quantos registros retornariam na minha linha?  `var d = await _db.Dominios.Where(x => x.idUsu == userID).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Aí depende da organização do seu Mock. A vantagem da minha proposta em relação ao Moq é que você efetivamente testa com dados, mesmo que inventados. Portanto, as contagens são conhecidas por você.

Comment: Então, é essa organização do Mock que me fez criar a pergunta :)

Comment: Se quiser, posso expandir aquela resposta dentro de um contexto mais especializado pra você. O que acha?

Comment: Acho ótimo, na verdade eu já implementei a sua resposta no código, só não fechei a pergunta porque ainda não entendi como eu poderia testar essa parte do código que coloquei na pergunta, mas o meu código já está usando a sua solução.

Comment: Ok, te escrevo isso amanhã.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não precisei `mockar` nada para pegar o resultado que eu queria. Apenas peguei o valor que já vinha no resultado e eu não sabia.

(Isso não vem ao caso) Eu coloquei uma forma diferente de mockar o `Indetify`.

No retorno eu pego o `result.Model`.

Segue o código do controle e do teste:

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
    public class DominioController : Controller
    {

        private IDominioDB _db;

        public DominioController(IDominioDB db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        // GET: Dominio
        public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
        {

            var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var d = await _db.Dominios.Where(x => x.idUsu == userID).ToListAsync();

            ViewBag.Username = User.Identity.Name;

            return View(d);
        }
    }
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public async Task VERIFICA_CONTROLE_DOMINIO()
        {

            //CRIANDO GENERICINDENTITY 
            string username = "Ricardo";
            string userid = "usuario1"; 

            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>{
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", username),
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", userid)
            };
            var genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
            genericIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

            var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, new string[] { "Ricardo" });
            //*************************


            //CRIANDO BASE DE DADOS PARA TESTE E FAZENDO O MOCK DO CONTEXTO
            var data = new List<DBDominio>()
            {
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario1" },
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario2" },new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario2" },
                new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario3" },new DBDominio() { idUsu = "usuario3" }
            }.AsQueryable();

            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<DBDominio>>();
            //*************************


            mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<DBDominio>>()
                .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<DBDominio>(data.GetEnumerator()));

            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<DBDominio>(data.Provider));


            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
            mockSet.As<IQueryable<DBDominio>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

            var repo = new Mock<Interfaces.IDominioDB>();
            repo.Setup(c => c.Dominios).Returns(mockSet.Object);


            //AQUI AO CRIAR O MOCK DE CONTROLLER EU FAÇO O SETUP COLOCANDO O IDENTITY PARA RETORNAR O GENERICIDENTITY CRIADO ACIMA
            var context = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            context.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext.User.Identity).Returns(genericIdentity);


            //AO CRIAR O OBJETO CONTROLER EU PASSO O CONTEXTO COM O INDENTITY NELE.
            // Arrange
            DominioController controller = new DominioController(repo.Object)
            {
                ControllerContext = context.Object,

            };

            // Act
            ViewResult result = (ViewResult)await controller.Index();
            var resultModel = (IEnumerable<DBDominio>)result.Model;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual(result.ViewBag.Username , "Ricardo");
            Assert.AreEqual(resultModel.Count(), 1);

        }
```