# Como testar Filtros que verificam dados das Claims?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testes, testes-funcionais

Possuo um `ActionFilter` para alguns *controllers* e *actions* que fazem uso das informações do usuário que estão nas *claims*.

O próprio filtro obtém as informações das *claims* do usuário e executa o processo de validação da autorização:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (Perfil >= Perfil.Administrativo)
        return;

    var cookie = new CookieInfo(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

    if (Perfil == Perfil.Usuario)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Acesso inválido!";
        return;
    }

    if (Perfil <= Perfil.Suporte)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Index");
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Acesso inválido!";
    }
    ...
}
```

Como devo escrever/criar métodos de testes para testar a funcionalidade do filtro?

Answer (score 3):

Escreva um método que instancia o [contexto de execução](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutedcontext(v=vs.118).aspx) (que por sua vez instancia o atributo de autorização, que é um filtro) e faça um *mock* da requisição, mais ou menos assim:

```
public void TesteDoFiltroDeAutorizacao()
{
    var context = new ActionExecutedContext();
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://umenderecoqualquer/", "");
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    context.HttpContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextBase { Request = httpRequest, Response = httpResponse }, 
              new RouteData(), 
              new QualquerController());
    var filter = new MinhaAutorizacaoAttribute(/* Aqui acho que você passa um perfil, pelo que eu entendi */);

    filter.OnActionExecuted(context);

    Assert.True(/* Teste aqui context.Result */);
}
```

Comment: Sei que é apenas um exemplo, mas poderia ver a linha `context.HttpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);` ? O  s tipos são diferentes.. Acredito que vou precisar passar valores para o Principal, como na questão **[como-testar-um-controler-asp-net-mvc-usando-moq-e-entity-framework](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90878/como-testar-um-controler-asp-net-mvc-usando-moq-e-entity-framework-6?rq=1)**. Eu consigo passar de alguma forma indo por este caminho? Grato!

Comment: Verdade, troquei na resposta para `ControllerContext`. `ControllerContext` possui uma propriedade chamada `User`, em que você pode usar para *mockar* `IPrincipal`.

Comment: o `new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse)` passados para o `new ControllerContext` são de tipos diferentes.

Comment: Atualizei para [HttpContextBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpcontextbase(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Como resolvi:

```
protected static ActionExecutedContext FakeExecutedContext(IPrincipal principal = null, 
    Controller controller = null)
{
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    request.SetupGet(x => x.HttpMethod).Returns("GET");
    request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://example.com/action"));

    var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    // aqui adiciono o principal quando passado por parâmetro
    if (principal != null)
        httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.User).Returns(principal);

    var executedContext = new Mock<ActionExecutedContext>();
    executedContext.SetupGet(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);
    if (controller != null)
        executedContext.SetupGet(x => x.Controller).Returns(controller);

    return executedContext.Object;
}
```

Simplificando o método de teste para isso:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TentativaDeAcessoComPerfilInferiorAoSolicitadoPeloFiltro()
{
    // variáveis
    // Uma claim será setada com nível de acesso de Suporte
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.Perfil, Perfil.Suporte.ToString())
    });

    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new[] { "" });

    // A simulação requer um nível de acesso Administrativo
    var filter = new PerfilFilterAttribute(Perfil.Administrativo, Context);
    var fakeExecutedContext = FakeExecutedContext(principal, new HomeController());

    // execução
    filter.OnActionExecuted(fakeExecutedContext);

    // validação
    // O resultado deve apontar um redirecionamento para o /Home/Index
    Assert.IsNotNull(fakeExecutedContext.Controller.TempData["ErrorMessage"]);
    Assert.IsNotNull(fakeExecutedContext.Result as RedirectResult);
    Assert.AreEqual(((RedirectResult)fakeExecutedContext.Result).Url, "/Home/Index");
}
```

Há um detalhe no filtro, que foi mudado de:

```
var cookie = new CookieInfo(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
```

Para:

```
var cookie = new CookieInfo(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
```

Comment: Usei o framework Moq

Comment: Ótimo trabalho. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um foreach nos seus Claims salvos da seguinte maneira:

```
IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> Claims = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims;
foreach (var t in Claims)
{
    if(t.Type.Equals("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid"))
        idUsuario = t.Value;
}
```